# Used BFG to remove large files from repo, but missing branches

Tags: git, gitlab, bfg-repo-cleaner, merge-request

In gitlab, there were 3 branches: master, UAT and NEWCOCOAPODS.  I used BFG and successfully removed 3 large files.  After pushing back up to gitlab, only master is there.  The output includes:

remote: To create a merge request for NEWCOCOAPODS, visit:
remote:   https://git.loomissayles.com/architecture-team/IOMobile/-/merge_requests/new?merge_request%5Bsource_branch%5D=NEWCOCOAPODS
remote:
remote:
remote: To create a merge request for UAT, visit:
remote:   https://git.loomissayles.com/architecture-team/IOMobile/-/merge_requests/new?merge_request%5Bsource_branch%5D=UAT

How do I restore these other two branches?  I'm not sure what a merge request is and don't want to further damage the project.

Thanks!

Comment: I should add that the other branches seem to exist in gitlab, but cloning from gitlab only gives me master in the local repo.

Comment: When you clone you only have the default local branch. Type `git branch -r` to see all the remote branches as well.

Answer (score 0):

A simple

```
git checkout UAT
```

did the trick.

My git GUI frontend did not display the other origin branches, so I did not originally see them.